# What happens with history when we make git reset --soft?

Tags: git, github

When I check my files after commits sometimes I can find some mistakes. In this case I always reset files from commit to staged with `git reset --soft HEAD^`, fix and make `git commit` again.
But I haven't ever thought what happens with history files, which where removed from branch with `git reset --soft`. What happens with old branch commits when we make `git reset --soft HEAD^`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens with old branch commits

Facts to know first: A branch is just a name pointing to a commit. Commits are *reachable* backwards thru time through the chain of commit parentage. The totality of all commits reachable from some branch (or tag) constitutes precisely the "history" of which you speak.

By resetting the branch pointer back to an earlier commit, you make the "old branch commits" *unreachable* from any branch pointer. Unreachable commits are not part of the history.

Nevertheless, an unreachable commit remains in the repo for a while (typically a couple of weeks) where it can be retrieved if desired. In this case, you could easily retrieve it via the `reflog`.

Then if it remains unreachable it is automatically deleted via garbage collection.

So, in short, the answer is: the "old commits" go into the trash, and eventually the trash is emptied.

Answer (score 3):

`git reset --soft HEAD^` only moves the current branch pointer to the parent commit and leaves the working tree and index unchanged.

It does not have any effect on any existing commits, except that the commit the branch pointer pointed to before may not be reachable anymore if there are no other references to it, and may eventually be garbage-collected.

Since you did this to correct a mistake in said commit, it seems this is what you want.